# Transformation matrix and kernel

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

I have some doubts regarding linear transformations.

The question states:

$T: \mathbb{R^3}\to\mathbb{R^3}$ is a linear transformation such that:

$T(\vec{e}_1)=\vec{e}_1-\vec{e}_2+2\vec{e}_3$

$T(\vec{e}_1+\vec{e}_2)=2\vec{e}_3$

$T(\vec{e}_1+\vec{e}_2+\vec{e}_3)=-\vec{e}_2+\vec{e}_3$

1. Calculate the transformation matrix
2. Calculate the dimension of the kernel of the transformation, justify.

Also, is there any reason why this uses $\vec{e}$ instead of x? If so, what does $\vec{e}$ mean exactly?

And although it isn't asked, how is the range calculated?

I thought maybe question 1 could be solved by finding $T(\vec{e}_1),T(\vec{e}_2) $ and $T(\vec{e}_3)$, which would respectively be $\vec{e}_1-\vec{e}_2+2\vec{e}_3$ ; $-\vec{e}_1+\vec{e}_2$ ; $-\vec{e}_2-\vec{e}_3$ (I think, I hope I haven't mistaken myself in the calculations). But I don't know what to do next, and I also have no thoughts on how to solve 2.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a guess:  $\vec{e}_1$ means $(1,0,0)\in \mathbb{R}^3$, $\vec{e}_2$ means $(0,1,0)$, $\vec{e}_2$ means $(0,0,1)$.  To find the dimension of  the kernel you need to ascertain the space of those vectors $x$ for which $T(x)=0$, which is the kernel, and figure out what its dimension is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, you almost solve it the only thing remaining it's to find the matrix. So we have
$$T(\vec e_1 ) = \vec e_1 - \vec e_2 + 2\vec e_3$$
$$T(\vec e_2) = -\vec e_1 + \vec e_2 + 0\vec e_3$$
$$T(\vec e_3)= 0\vec e_1-\vec e_2 - \vec e_3$$
Then using the coefficients of the first equation for the numbers in the first column in the matrix associated with T. We have
$$A_T=\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -1 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & -1 \\
2 & 0 & -1
 \end{array} \right]$$
Then making Gauss elimination you need to find the number of free variables and that number is the dimension of the kernel; in this case $dim(Ker A_T)= 0$, in other words $Rank(A_T)=3$. And remember that $Ker(T)=Ker(A_T)$, $dim(Ker T)=dim(Ker A_T)$, and the same with the rank of $T$.

And for the last part we have to choose two basis for $\mathbb R^3$ one for the domain and the other for the codomain. The easiest one is the canonical basis $\{ \vec e_1, \vec e_2, \vec e_3\}$ but note that you can choose a different basis for both.

Comment: Thank you. I just have one more question. Having represented the transformation matrix what would be the correct notation to describe the equation resulting from each line? (I apologise for not being able to be more specific). For example, would it be correct to write x - y = 0, for the first line? Or would "x" and "y" not be the right variables to use since our problem started with these canonical basis vectors denoted by $\vec e$?

Comment: You are correct, we can write $T(x,y,z)=(x-y+2z,-x+y,-y-z)$ and remember that x,y,z are just letters, you can choose any letter you want like r,s,t; but x,y,z are the most common one.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer to a part of your question:

"Is there any reason why this uses $\vec e$ instead of $x?$ If so, what does $\vec e$ mean exactly?"

$T$ is a map which has its domain *vectors* in $\Bbb R^3$, not real numbers. Usually $x,y,z$ are used for unknown or variable real numbers.

$\vec e_1,\vec e_2,\vec e_3,$ are the standard basis vectors in $\Bbb R^3$ and are defined as:

$$\vec e_1=\begin{bmatrix} 
1\\
0\\
0\\
 \end{bmatrix},
\vec e_2=\begin{bmatrix} 
0\\
1\\
0\\
 \end{bmatrix},
\vec e_3=\begin{bmatrix} 
0\\
0\\
1\\
 \end{bmatrix}, $$